# Fuel filler neck has 1 broken pipe of 3. What is its purpose?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, fuel-leak

I'm trying to fix a gas leak in my filler neck before a 2000 mile trip on 6/28/17...
2002 Mitsubishi Elcipse 3.0L

I just pulled off my wheel and the filler neck cover and found 1 of the 3 pipes broken apart.  It was one of the 2 smaller pipes.  I poured a very small amount of fuel additive and didn't see a leak.  I should mention that there was a lot of debris, probably clogging the broken pipe.  So I suppose my main concern right now is **how will the small broken pipe affect my fuel system and what exactly does it do, also considering that it is probably clogged with dirt?**

**Also, is this where my leak is coming from?** About half of a pint is spilled after my average fillup.

I have a small evap leak according to my engine code reader.

[image][image: Obviously the previous owner had a problem before me.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the big pipe is the fuel filler pipe (obviously). The 2 other ones hook into a pipe for fuel tank vent for vapor and the charcoal canister as part of the evaporative system. It appears as a small leak because the small tube is clogged otherwise it would be large leak. The solution change out the filler pipe assembly and reconnect the hoses.